# Value of Age didn't appear in my project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this model:

```
 [DisplayName("Date of Birth:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birth Date is Required.")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Date of Birth is Selected.")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Age:")]
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
            int age = now.Year - BirthDate.Year;
            if (BirthDate > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
            return age;
        }

    }
```

And in My Partial View:

```
 <div class="editor">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "date" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
 </div>

 <div class="editor">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
 @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Age)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
 </div>
```

And once the Birthday is filled the Age doesn't display the calculated age. 
Let me know if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to supply both a setter and getter for binding to work properly.

Try adding the setter for Age, even if it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I already add a setter for the Age, but still no luck it doesn't appear in my create form. Please help me. What am I missing?

Comment: '     public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Employee/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Employees.Add(employee);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(employee);
        }'